# Multiple threads in a for-loop using a parameterized function(x, y, z)

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have a list which contains folder ID's and folder paths. I would like to pass some of these folders to a function which zips them.  What I want is to have three threads run in parallel and zip three different paths at a time. What happens now is each thread waits until the next one has finished in order to process the next. Any ideas?

```
Dim SelectedRange = From folders In listFolders Where folders.FolderID >= 150101

For Each item In SelectedRange
    Dim t As New Thread(
        Sub()
            Me.BeginInvoke(DirectCast(Sub() ZipFolder(sInclearDestination, item.FolderID.ToString, item.FolderPath), MethodInvoker))
        End Sub)
    t.Start()
    t.Join()
Next
```

---

```
Public Function ZipFolder(ByVal sFolderPathDestination As String, ByVal folderID As String, ByVal folderPath As String) As Boolean
    Try
        Using zip = New Ionic.Zip.ZipFile()
            'If the zip file does not exist then get the folder and zip it to the destination
            If Not File.Exists(Path.Combine(sFolderPathDestination, folderID & ".zip")) Then
                zip.AddDirectory(folderPath)
                zip.Save(Path.Combine(sFolderPathDestination, CType(folderID, String) & ".zip"))
                Return True
            Else
                Logging.Log("Aborting zipping: " & Path.Combine(sFolderPathDestination, folderID & ".zip") & ". The zip file already exists!")
                Return False
            End If
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Logging.Log("Error in zipping: " & Path.Combine(sFolderPathDestination, folderID & ".zip") & " Error: " & ex.Message)
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems with your code.

The first problem is the call to `Me.BeginInvoke`.  Presumably you are creating a WinForm application and `Me` is a reference to the current `Form`.  The `Form.BeginInvoke` (inherited from the base `Control` class) causes the given delegate to be executed on the UI thread.  So, all you are doing is creating three separate threads which all immediately invoke back to the UI thread to do all of their work.  You obviously can't do that and still expect the tasks to be processed in parallel.  You need to remove the call to `BeginInvoke`.  If you need to call `BeginInvoke` in-order to update the display of some data on the form, you need to do it as late as possible and do as little work as possible within that UI-invoked code so that the majority of the work is still being done in the worker threads.

The second problem is the call to `Thread.Join`.  You are calling `Join` inside your `For` loop right after starting the thread.  That means that it will sit there and wait, at that call to `Join`, until the worker thread is complete.  Therefore, your loop waits for each thread to complete before starting the next one, in essence, making it single threaded.  You should just remove the call to `Join`.  If you need the calling method to wait for all the threads to complete, just wait to call `Join` on the threads until *all* of them have been started (i.e. after the `For` loop).

Comment: I have changed it to the following but it's still zipping one at a time...  Dim t As New Thread(Sub()
                                    ZipFolder(sInclearDestination, item.FolderID.ToString, item.FolderPath)
                                End Sub)

Comment: Does the `ZipFolder` method, inside of itself, ever invoke to the UI thread?

Comment: No. I will post my zipFolder function on the question.

Comment: All that looks ok.  If it's still not running in parallel, then it's quite possible that the `Ionic.Zip.ZipFile` class uses `SyncLock`, or some similar mechanism, to stop multiple threads from writing to the same file at the same time.  I'm not familiar with that library, so I couldn't say for sure, but it seems like a likely thing for it to do.

Comment: By the way, how do you know that they aren't being done in parallel?  Via breakpoints, or some other method?

Comment: When I removed the "t.join" the zips started all together. (I'm not good with multithreading). Would this cause any problems?

Comment: Oh, right.  I missed that.  That makes sense.  The `Join` was causing the calling thread to wait until the worker thread finished before starting the next one.  Sorry about that.  No, as long as that zipping library is thread-safe, there should be no problems.  You definitely should not have been calling `Join` there, as it wouldn't ever make sense to do that.

Comment: I have accepted your answer. If you add the above comment it would make the answer better.

Comment: Steven, how would I ensure that only 3 threads run concurrently instead of having x number of threads executing something that drains the memory of the pc?

Comment: Well, you could do a `For i  = 1 To 3` loop and call `Joins` on all three threads after starting all three.  Then have an outer loop that keeps doing that until the list has been completely processed.  Or, the more simple solution is to use the `ThreadPool` class to start your threads.  That's the whole purpose of it.